# How to do one executor wait for another?

Tags: java, runnable

I have two tasks, one for download and another for unzip;

```
public class DownloadUtil {

    public static void downloadHtml(MainViewController controller, String dns, int port, String offlineUUID, String filePath, Map<String, String> cookies) throws IOException {

        String urlHtml = "http://" + dns + ":" + port + Constants.TARGET_SERVICE_DOWNLOADFILES + offlineUUID;

        System.out.println(urlHtml);

        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new DownloaderTask(controller, urlHtml, filePath, cookies));
    }
```

and

```
public class UnzipUtil {

    public static void unZipIt(String zipFile, String outputFolder) {

        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new UnzipTask(zipFile, outputFolder));
    }
}
```

and I call them in my code this way:

```
DownloadUtil.downloadHtml(this, dns, port, uuid, filePathHtmlDownload, cookies);
UnzipUtil.unZipIt(filePathHtmlDownload, outputFolder);
```

But the problem is that the Unzip method is calling before the download method finish, how can I do to unZipIt wait for downloadHtml method?

Comment: Don't do them both at the same time? Seems ... logical.

Comment: Just let them use the same executor instead of two separate executors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the same `SingleThreadExecutor` to both methods. Your tasks are then done sequentially by the `Executor`.

```
Executor e = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
DownloadUtil.downloadHtml(e, this, dns, port, uuid, filePathHtmlDownload, cookies);
UnzipUtil.unZipIt(e, filePathHtmlDownload, outputFolder);
```

And your methods now look like:

```
public class DownloadUtil {

public static void downloadHtml(Executor e, MainViewController controller, String dns, int port, String offlineUUID, String filePath, Map<String, String> cookies) throws IOException {

    ...

    e.execute(new DownloaderTask(controller, urlHtml, filePath, cookies));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). It will be helpful in your case. You can create one latch for both threads and when download will be complete you can execute `countDown()`. In beginning of unzip you can place something like `latch.await()`. So, unzipping will start only when download will be complete.